# Admob adaptive anchor banner

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads

for Admob banner ads, adaptive ads banner, What is the difference between `getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize` and `getCurrentOrientationInlineAdaptiveBannerAdSize`

Which one has better user experience?

And which one generate more revenue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

`getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize`
([anchored adaptive banners](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner/anchored-adaptive))

> When to use adaptive banners
>
> Adaptive banners are designed to be a drop-in replacement for the
> industry standard 320x50 banner size, as well as the smart banner
> format they supersede.
>
> These banner sizes are commonly used as anchored banners, which are
> usually locked to the top or bottom of the screen. For such anchored
> banners, the aspect ratio when using adaptive banners will be similar
> to that of a standard 320x50 ad, as can be seen in these screenshots

`getCurrentOrientationInlineAdaptiveBannerAdSize` ([inline adaptive banners](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner/inline-adaptive))

> When to use inline adaptive banners
>
> Inline adaptive banners are larger, taller banners compared to
> anchored adaptive banners. They are of variable height, and can be as
> tall as the device screen.
>
> They are intended to be placed in scrolling content